# If the length of a curve on $[0,s_0]$ is $s_0$ then $\|\gamma'(s)\|=1$ for all $s\in [0,b]$

Tags: calculus

Let $\gamma :[0,b]\to \Bbb{R}^d$ be $C_1[0,b]$ (I am not sure about the range, since the question didn't specify, but this is Calculus 4(which is in EN sources III-IV) so I assume the range is $\Bbb{R}^d$). If the length of a curve on $[0,s_0]$ is $s_0$, ($L_{[0,s_0]}(\gamma)=s_0$) then $\|\gamma'(s)\|=1$ for all $s\in [0,b]$.

I am a little confused and not sure how I can show it. I thought that instead of using the formula: $$\int^{s}_{0}\|\gamma'(t)\|dt=s=\int_{0}^{s}1\cdot dt$$ which I am not sure is enough to directly conclude that the integrand is $1$, I thought I should make sure I understand why it is correct and see the limit for myself.

To put this problem in words, since the length of the curve between $s$ and $s+h$ is $h$, the distance $\|\gamma(s+h)-\gamma(s)\|$ converges to the distance $|s+h-s|$ giving $\lim_{h\to 0}{\|\gamma(t+h)-\gamma(t)\|\over h}\cong 1$, but showing it rigorously is where I fail.

The length  of the curve at a given point $t$ is $t$ and the length at $t+h$ is $t+h$, so the length of the curve on $[s,s+h]$ is:
partitioning $[t,t+h]=[t,t+{h\over n}]\cup...\cup[t+{(n-1)h\over n}]\cup[t+h]$, $[0,t]=[0,{t\over n}]\cup...\cup[{(n-1)t\over n},t]$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\|\gamma({tj\over n})-\gamma({t(j-1)\over n})\|}=L_{[0,t]}$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\|\gamma({tj\over n})-\gamma({t(j-1)\over n})\|}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\|\gamma(t+{hj\over n})-\gamma(t+{h(j-1)\over n})\|})$ which by definition also equals $L_{[0,t+h]}\gamma$ we get $L_{[0,t]}\gamma+L_{[t,t+h]}\gamma=L_{[0,t+h]}\gamma$ so, $t+L_{[t,t+h]}\gamma=t+h$ giving the desired result $L_{[t,t+h]}\gamma=h$.

How do I show that the ratio between the distance of images of two values and the distance of those time values converges to $1$ as the values approach each other? Because if $L_{[t,t+h]}=\lim_{k\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\|\gamma(t+{hi\over k})-\gamma(t+{h(i-1)\over k})\|$, so $\|\gamma(t+{h\over k})-\gamma (t)\|$ converges to zero, and at most the last expression is not bigger than ${h\over k}$ but I guess it doesn't help me much. I tried all sorts of partitioning but since using index partitions that get smaller, while $h$ also get smaller somehow confuses me and I can't derive an equation out of it.
I could really use some guidance how to proceed in this fashion.

Comment: Can you just differentiate both sides of $s = \int_0^s |\gamma'(t)|dt$?

Comment: The assumption for a single $s_0$ is certainly not enough. Either you assume it *for all* $s_0$ (then the comment of @ArcticChar gives the conclusion) or you have to impose additionally $\|\gamma'(t)\|\le 1$ for all $t$.

Comment: Thank you so much!
I really overlooked this option.